# autofill independant form with joomla user data

Tags: forms, joomla, autofill

I'm using Joomla and a form independent of Joomla located in a separate folder on the site.

If the user is logged into Joomla I'd like the name and email of this form to be populated with the user's data.

I'm trying something like the following, but it's not working:

```
 <?php jimport('joomla.user.helper');
       $user = JFactory::getUser();
       $name = $user->name;
       $email = $user->email;
       ?>
```

And then this in the value of the field:

```
<?php return $email ?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If I understand you, you are trying to get user data from stand alone script. This code would work fine in some module or component, but  as standalone you do not have access to this data. You shoud include framework.php. Google for more info.

Comment: It would be so much easier to use a normal Joomla form within Joomla for example by using one of the form extensions.  You can't just call a Joomla  class without an application.  You could try to share a session using the session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the contents of the "index.php" file located under the root directory of your Joomla website, but remove the last line which is this one:

```
$app->execute();
```

Now paste the above in the php file displaying the form.

Now your next step would be to know which user is logged in to the Joomla website, but it won't be straightforward since you are not in the Joomla environment. What you can do is pass the Joomla session ID to the other website in a link and then store the session ID (of the Joomla website) in a session variable on another website. You can then retrieve the user ID of the Joomla website based on the stored session ID.

Not very easy but it'll work.

Comment: Well I would share the session by using the session cookie and querying the session table.